# add folder to folder using google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

The script below is creating folders within a parent folder using 
"google drive API". It works perfectly however, after a while (20 folders or so) it is not working anymore.
No error message just no more folder creation within the parent folder.
It goes somewhere else!

To enable that creation a "service account" was created and parent folder is share between "personal google account" and "service account"

Can someone provide help please?

```
php function send_google_drive($id,$fileno,$filename1,$filename2){
        global $wpdb;
        require(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/enemat/googledrives/vendor/autoload.php');
        $client = getClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        if(!empty($filename1)){ 
            $results = $service->files->listFiles();
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == 'ENEMAT CRM FILES') {
                    $folderId = $item['id'];
                    break;
                }
            }
            $parentid = $folderId;
            $childid = "";
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == $fileno) {
                    $childid = $item['id'];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(empty($childid)){
                $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                    'name' => $fileno,
                                    'parents'=>array($parentid),
                                    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
                                    $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                    'fields' => 'id'));
                 $folderId = $file->id;
             }else{
                $folderId = $childid;
             }
                $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
                $newPermission->setType('anyone');
                $newPermission->setRole('reader');
                $service->permissions->create($folderId, $newPermission);

                $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                            'name' => array(basename($filename1)),
                            'parents' => array($folderId)
                        ));
                        $content = file_get_contents($filename1);
                        $files = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                'data' => $content,
                                'uploadType' => 'resumable',
                                'fields' => 'id')); 
                $fileids = $files->id; 
                $docusignorgs = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=".$fileids."";
                $folderslink = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/".$folderId."";
                @unlink(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/pdfs/".basename($filename1));
                $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
                $newPermission->setType('anyone');
                $newPermission->setRole('reader');
                $service->permissions->create($fileids, $newPermission);

        }

        if(!empty($filename2)){ 
            $results = $service->files->listFiles();
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == '46 - CONTRAT PARTENARIAT') {
                    $folderId = $item['id'];
                    break;
                }
            }

                $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                            'name' => array(basename($filename2)),
                            'parents' => array($folderId)
                        ));
                        $content = file_get_contents($filename2);
                        $files = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                'data' => $content,
                                'uploadType' => 'resumable',
                                'fields' => 'id')); 
                $fileids1 = $files->id; 
                $contractdrivelink = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=".$fileids1."";
                $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
                $newPermission->setType('anyone');
                $newPermission->setRole('reader');
                $service->permissions->create($fileids1, $newPermission);


        }

    }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no error message is because your code has no error handling! If GDrive fails to do something, it returns an error code and message to explain why. Your code should be catching that error and displaying it.

My guess is that you are hitting a rate limit. To see if this is the cause or not, add a 2 second delay between each folder creation. If it no runs correctly, you know that rate limiting is your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot pinoyyyid! could you pls provide me the piece of code to get error handling? thanks

Comment: If you don't know how to implement error handling in PHP, try asking a colleague or post a new question on SO using the `php` tag.

Comment: Hello, all is working perfectly but after a while , folder creation is not anymore in the parent folder. it is lost somewhere in google drive however a link is created that works and open the file uploaded by service account! There is an issue I think with permission or the fact that folder is created by a service account that is shared with my personal google account. It is really frustrating . I appreciate your great help @pimoyyid! pls let me know?

Comment: Approximately 24 hours it worked properly and create new folders or send files in shared folders but after 24 hours lost share folders permissions and got this error in logs:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: .",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: ."
 }
}
Please help

Comment: @piniyyid help pls

Comment: you haven't provided enough information for anybody to help you

Comment: HEllo pinoyyid, I have implemented error handling and i have pasted the error what else do you need pls? thanks